# Dynamically setting height in Internet Explorer translates to height: auto

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

This script takes the height value of each span element and applies it to its parent li element ( I wrote it to solve some float / layout issues). It works perfectly in Firefox and Chrome: after execution, I check the html and everything has worked alright.

However, in IE 7 and 8 (havent bothered trying with IE6, screw that) it doesnt work properly. Instead, it sets all li's height to auto.

This is my code:

```
$(".fase ol > li").each(function(index) {
  var li_content_height = $('span', this).css('height');
  $(this).css('height', li_content_height )
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="fase">
  <ol>
    <li>
      <span>blablablablabla</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>blablablablabla</span>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried using [height](http://api.jquery.com/height/) instead?

```
var li_content_height = $('span').height() + $(this).height();
$(this).css('height', li_content_height);
```

If you want the height including padding or margin, then you can use [outerHeight](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/):

```
var heightWithPadding = $('span').outerHeight();
var heightWithPaddingAndMargin = $('span').outerHeight(true);
```

Comment: I just tried using height(), and it doesnt work in IE either. Thank you, though.

Comment: It does not set the height of the li elements to the value of the span height, it sets it to auto.

Comment: Did you try outerHeight instead?

Comment: Shit, sorry, but height() DOES work, but I had to use $('span', this)height().

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Huh? Where are you defining an explicit height? Did you mean to do `$('span', this).height()`?

Would be useful if you provided a demo of the real code so we understand the context in regards to the layout/design...

**Edit: You should show us your *real* underlying problem and layout so we can help you solve it without using scripting.**

**Edit #2**: Without your scripting, the `1`'s become `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` properly. The horizontal margin becomes a little inconsistent. You should be able to just `zoom:1` on the `li`. I think you need to refactor your CSS instead of rely on scripting, positive it can be solved without it. Also, you have [serious markup issues](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.esferaliacapital.com/asesoramiento-en-materia-de-inversion&charset=(detect+automatically)&doctype=Inline&group=0) because some tags are not closed properly, validate it.

Comment: That won't work. You must get the heights separately. See my example: http://jsfiddle.net/C3k6N/. That should of returned "20" but it returned "10". Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/C3k6N/1/

Comment: My advice was never meant for multiple elements, I meant individually. Should be trivial to add them. His example does not contain multiple span siblings, so I didn't take that into account.

Comment: if it wasn't meant for multiple elements, what's with the `$('span', this).height()` example ;)?

Comment: Does his example contain multiple span siblings? If he had specified that in his example, I would take that into account. Otherwise it just picks up one, based on his html.

Comment: I think I'm missing something here, does `$('span', this)` have a signifant meaning? I assumed that it would just return the first element's height?

Answer (score 1):

Use `.height()` instead of `.css('height')`